# Getting oracle connection and using?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using java1.6 and spring. I have oracle11g database. I am setting `Connection` object to my bean on `start up`.

```
public  class MyBean{


//This value will be set during applicaiton context startup
Connection connection;

}
```

So here Connection object is set during only application context. `My question is consider my application acquired connection and connection object is initialized. After that if something happens on database end and connection is broken`. Now as my bean already contains connection object and if i try to use the same connection object then do i have any issues? Because that connection is already lost due to database restart or something.
How can i overcome this issue? Am not using any connection pooling mechanism. I am using plain `JDBC`.

Thanks!

Comment: Using JDBC does not mean you can't use connection pooling. The usual way is to use a `Datasource` (Spring provides several implementations, depending on your needs) or you can get one from the container.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use connection pooling. In the same function, you should get a connection from the datasource, use it, and close it as quickly as possible in a try/catch/finally block. You should not hold onto connections. Its a bad idea. Among other things, the database only as a limited number of connections to hand out. Don't hog them.

Dont' worry about any performance loss by using and closing pooled connections countless times compared to holding onto a connection. That's what its designed for. You should use a try/catch/finally block in your function and close the connection in the finally block.